# How to implement role based method level authorization in springboot on an architecture with 4 micro-services, eureka server and API gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul, api-gateway, jwt

I have a springboot application with 4 microservices, eureka server and a centralised API gateway. I have performed authentication using jwt token at api gateway and now i want to implement role based security on methods which are present in microservices other than gateway. I have tried to use **@PreAuthorize** but its not working out of the gateway. Is there any solution to achieve this type of security ?

Comment: IM facing similar challenge - what did you end up doing after all?